DevExpress XtraReport Table space between rows
I'm trying to create table in code using DevExpress with data from data source
here my class
Public Class XtraReport2
    Inherits XtraReport

    Private GLB_TABLENAME As String = "CUSTOM_TABLE"

    Public Sub New(reportModel As ClassReport)

        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable(GLB_TABLENAME)
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)

        Dim connectionString As String = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TnA_DBConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Try
                Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
                Dim command As New SqlCommand(reportModel.SQL, connection)
                Dim commandTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("REPORT_Command_Timeout")
                If commandTimeout <> "" Then
                    command.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout
                End If
                adapter.SelectCommand = command
                Dim rowsCount = adapter.Fill(ds, GLB_TABLENAME)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Using

        GenerateReport(ds)

    End Sub

    Private Sub GenerateReport(dataset As DataSet)
        DirectCast(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.Margins.Left = 30
        Me.Margins.Right = 30
        Me.PaperKind = Printing.PaperKind.A4
        Me.Landscape = False
        Me.Bands.Clear()
        DirectCast(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()

        Me.DataSource = dataset
        Me.DataMember = GLB_TABLENAME

        Dim tablePadding = 1
        Dim tableWidth = Me.PageWidth - Me.Margins.Left - Me.Margins.Right - tablePadding * 2

        Dim table = XRTable.CreateTable(New Rectangle(tablePadding, 3, tableWidth, 40), 1, 0)
        With table
            .Width = tableWidth
            .Borders = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.All
            .BorderWidth = 0.3
            .CanGrow = True
            .CanShrink = True
            .BeginInit()
        End With

        For i As Integer = dataset.Tables(GLB_TABLENAME).Columns.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            Dim dc As DataColumn = dataset.Tables(GLB_TABLENAME).Columns(i)
            Dim binding As New XRBinding("Text", dataset, dataset.Tables(GLB_TABLENAME).Columns(i).ColumnName)
            Dim cell As New XRTableCell()
            cell.DataBindings.Add(binding)
            table.Rows.FirstRow.Cells.Add(cell)
        Next

        table.EndInit()

        Dim detail = New DetailBand()
        detail.Height = table.Height
        detail.Controls.Add(table)

        Dim band = New Band() {detail}
        Me.Bands.AddRange(band)
    End Sub

End Class

But it's generating space between rows like this attached image

I have tried everything I can, but it's not working so please help
My DevExpress version is: 20.1
I have searched in DevExpress documentation and google a lot for a week
